# How can I get all active sessions with Apache Shiro ehcache-terracotta?

Tags: ehcache, shiro, terracotta

In my maven application, I want to provide that if a user log in a new account, another account that already open will be log out. I am using Apache shiro, ehcache and terracotta for this.
I want to get all active sessions to check whether that user is logined previously. I can take users and their session id from all servers using Hazelcast(this works), but i can not take session (because it is not serializable)

I use clustered servers in project. Servers have same ip address but their ports are different.
x.x.x.x:7002 -->server1,
x.x.x.x:7003 -->server2
how can i define that ports in ehcache configuration file?
how can i take all active sessions from that ports with terracotta?

Please help

ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache>
<terracottaConfig url="x.x.x.x:9510"/>

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/shiro-ehcache"/>
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="120"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    diskPersistent="false"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120">
    <!-- <terracotta/>-->
</defaultCache>
<cache name="myactiveSessionCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       eternal="true"
       timeToLiveSeconds="0"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       diskPersistent="false"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="600">
    <!-- <terracotta/>-->
</cache>
<!-- Add more cache entries as desired, for example,
Realm authc/authz caching: -->
</ehcache>
```

shiro.ini:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
cacheManager .cacheManagerConfigFile = classpath:ehcache.xml
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager 
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

Login.java:

```
User newuser = ..//get from db with username and password
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
Subject currentUser = new Subject.Builder().buildSubject();
token.setRememberMe(true);
currentUser = getSubject();
currentUser.login(token);

//at here, i take all active users and their's session id with Hazelcast. 
//and check that is 'newuser' in all active users list?
if (!activeuserList.containsKey(newuser)) {
    activeuserList.put(newuser, currentUser.getSession().getId());
} else {
    Serializable s = activeuserList.get(newuser);
    isSessionActive(s);
}
}

...
//check -- is session active?
public void isSessionActive(Serializable s) {
DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = (DefaultWebSecurityManager)   SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager();
DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManager = (DefaultWebSessionManager) securityManager.getSessionManager();
EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO sessionDao = (EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO) sessionManager.getSessionDAO();
Cache<Serializable, Session> activeSessionsCache = sessionDao.getActiveSessionsCache();
if (activeSessionsCache.keys().contains(s)) {
        //previous session is closed.
        activeuserList.remove(newuser);
        activeSessionsCache.get(s).stop();
        //new session id is added to list
        activeuserList.put(newuser, currentUser.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```